# symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the basis $β=\{(1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(2,1,0)\}$ for $\mathbb R^3$
Does the following matrix $A=[T]_β^β$ define symmetric mappings of $\mathbb R^3$?

\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 0 \\
2 &  0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Can I solve this problem by letting $A$ be the matrix above and find an orthonormal basis and show that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is: isn't it crystal clear that the matrix $\,A\,$ is a symmetric one? Then, what you're *exactly* asking?

Comment: I think the question could be: is $T$ symmetric with respect to the canonical basis. Since $\beta$ is not orthonormal, the fact that its matrix $A$ with respect to $\beta$ is symmetric does not say anything about $T$ being symmetric with respect to the canonical basis.

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, I have nothing to propose but compute the inverse of the change of basis matrix $P$, and then see if $PAP^{-1}$ is still symmetric.